# Unable to clear Modal when using Async

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using Blazor framework.

I had an EntryForm which used to generate few text boxes at run-time.

```
<!-- Input fields -->
@for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    var index = i;
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-sm-8" style="float:left">
            <div class="justify-content-center mb-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" @bind="myMod.Code[index]" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="float:left">
            <div class="justify-content-center mb-2">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" @bind="myMod.Weight[index]" @bind:event="oninput" />
            </div>
        </div>
    <div/>
}
```

There are two buttons after these controls, SAVE and CLOSE.

When user-clicks Save, I have a requirement to confirm from the user. So I added below code:

```
@code {
    private StudentModel myMod= new StudentModel();
    private void Save()
    {
            bool askUser = ValidateEntry();

            if (askUser)
            {
                Task.Run(async () => await ConfirmSave());
                myMod = new StudentModel();
            }
            else
                Task.Run(async () => await CreateFile());
        }

   async Task ConfirmSave()
    {
        bool confirmed = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", $"Are you sure?");
        if (confirmed)
        {
            await CreateFile();
        }
    }
}
```

When I was not asking confirmation using ConfirmSave async method, I was able to clear the model by just reinstantiating it. But now even if I do:

```
myMod = new StudentModel()
```

it is not clearing the model and therefore after SAVE, the fields retain the previously entered values.

How to clear the model and thereby all fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't await the Task.Run(). That means that the rendering that belongs to the ButtonClick is already running before you re-assign myMod.

But the better option is to not use Task.Run() at all.

```cs
async Task Save()
{
   ...
   if()
   {
      //Task.Run(async () => await ConfirmSave());
      await ConfirmSave();
      myMod = new StudentModel();
   } 
   else
     //Task.Run(async () => await CreateFile());
     await CreateFile();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked. The only issue is if I don't want to make SAVE as async, and only want to call ConfirmSave, what is the option ?

Comment: Why not async? Blazor supports that very well: `@onclick="Save"` is all you need.  And you do need an `async Task` toplevel method.

Comment: Because from SAVE method I have calls to non-async methods as well. Though these are working with a call to async ConfirmSave, but I want to ensure these do not crash in future.

Comment: They won't crash in the future. Make things async when and where you can. Make sure you have an unbroken 'chain' of awaits and treat "lacks await' and 'is not awaited' Warnings as Errors.

Comment: And don't use Task.Run() .